# Kendo UI ComboBox Events

Tags: css, combobox, kendo-ui, background-color

I'm trying to change the color of a Kendo UI ComboBox depending on the item selected.

I've put together a fiddle showing the problem [[http://jsfiddle.net/PeWPE/]](http://jsfiddle.net/PeWPE/)

What I need to do is determine the selected item when the page loads.  I can trap the onDataBound event, but can't find the selected item at that point - I suspect that it is not available.

When the user selects a new item from the list the select event gives me all of the data I need to change the color of the ComboBox, although the color isn't actually changing :(

So, in summary, is there a way to change the color of a kendo ui ComboBox when the initial value is set (and any help with fixing my syntax would be good too!).

Thanks for your help.

Here's the code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // Create some data - including a color
 var data = [{
     text: "12 Angry Men",
     value: "1",
     color: "White"
 }, {
     text: "Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo.",
     value: "2",
     color: "White"
 }, {
     text: "Inception",
     value: "3",
     color: "Green"
 }, {
     text: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
     value: "4",
     color: "Green"
 }, {
     text: "Pulp Fiction",
     value: "5",
     color: "Blue"
 }, {
     text: "Schindler's List",
     value: "6",
     color: "Blue"
 }, {
     text: "The Dark Knight",
     value: "7",
     color: "Red"
 }, {
     text: "The Godfather",
     value: "8",
     color: "Red"
 }, {
     text: "The Godfather: Part II",
     value: "9",
     color: "Yellow"
 }, {
     text: "The Shawshank Redemption",
     value: "10",
     color: "Yellow"
 }, {
     text: "The Shawshank Redemption 2",
     value: "11",
     color: "Orange"
 }];

 // Create the combo
 $("#movies").kendoComboBox({
     dataTextField: "text",
     dataValueField: "value",
     dataSource: data,
     height: 100,
     change: onChange,
     dataBound: onDataBound,
     select: onSelect
 });

 // Select a value - Note no event is raised when doing this(!)
 var combo = $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox");
 combo.value("9");

 function onChange(e) {
     alert('onChange Called');
     ctrl = this.element.attr("id");
     var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
 }

 // This is called - but the color is not being set
 function onSelect(e) {
     alert('onSelect Called');
     var ctrl = this.element.attr("id");
     var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
     alert('Control Id: ' +ctrl);     // Check we've got the control
     alert('Color selected: ' + dataItem.color);
     $('input[name="' + ctrl + '_input"]').css({
         backgroundColor: dataItem.color
     });
     $('#movies').css({
         backgroundColor: dataItem.color
     });

 }

 function onDataBound(e) {
     alert('onDataBound Called');
 }

 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI decorates the HTML elements with their own. This is the way that they have to make it visually compatible among browser and platforms.

You should define your combobox as:

```
$("#movies").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField : "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource    : data,
    height        : 100,
    select        : onSelect,
    dataBound     : onDataBound,
    value         : 9
});
```

NOTE: that you might set the value in the definition, you don't need to do it afterwards.

And then define the two event handlers as:

```
function onSelect(e){
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    this.input.css({ 'background-color' : dataItem.color });
}

function onDataBound(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.value());
    this.input.css({ 'background-color' : dataItem.color });
}
```

`onSelect` is used when you change the value while `onDataBound` is used for the initial value.

A working Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/PeWPE/4/

Comment: Thanks for the help @OnaBai. Unfortunately I can't set the initial value in the kendoComboBox() markup, it is set by knockout, and at bind time there is no this.value to use. Any ideas how I can set the color in these circumstances at bind time?

Comment: Check this modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/PeWPE/8/. Where I invoke `trigger("select");` after setting the value. This is a going a little low level but is invoking what KendoUI does not invoked when we do `value(9)`. You might realize that I've removed any reference to `e` on `onSelect` since I'm not passing it as argument to `trigger`. If you need it you need to generate a compatible version of `e` and pass it to `trigger`. I've also removed `onDataBound` since it is not needed if you don't set an initial value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, there seems to be quite a lot not in the Kendo docs!

Comment: Getting better but still long way to go... But it is also true that it is pretty easy to start with and we don't read all the documentation available on their web (at least not me) :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you create a KendoUI Combobox on the #movies input, it actually hides that input and creates a new one. So the only issue is that the selectors you are using aren't correct. I've updated your jsFiddle reference, but if you change your onSelect method to the following, it will fix your issue.

```
function onSelect(e){
    var ctrl = this.element.attr("id");
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    var combobox = $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox");
    combobox.input.css({ 'background-color' : dataItem.color });
    combobox.list.css({ 'background-color' : dataItem.color });
}
```

It should fix your issue (it's adding the color in jsFiddle).

Comment: To further comment here - you use $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox") to get a reference back to the combobox object you created. That allows you to reference the list and input controls that it creates on the fly!

Comment: Thanks, that solves the setting of the color on manual selection of an item.  I'm still struggling with the initial setting of the color on dataBind.